# Reverse Engineering an 8 bit CRC

Tags: crc

I have a device that spits out data with a checksum of some kind (8bit), that I would like to reverse engineer.  (balboa spa wifi, for those interested).

The messages are:

7E1DFFAF130000640B2B00000100000400000000000000000064000000A57E

Where "7E" is the header/footer of the message,  1D is the length, and A5 in this case, is the checksum byte.

I've tried feeding these into reveng, but it just spits out "no models found" no matter how I set the parameters.  What am I doing wrong?

Some example data with the header/footer stripped off, checksums at the end:
1DFFAF130000640B2800000100000400000000000000000064000000D1
1DFFAF130000640B2900000100000400000000000000000064000000FD
1DFFAF130000640B2A0000010000040000000000000000006400000089
1DFFAF130000640B2B00000100000400000000000000000064000000A5

Thanks

Comment: Also worth noting,  FFAF13 is the "message type", so might not be part of the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

`reveng -w 8 -s` followed by those four strings gives me a result. However you don't have enough data to resolve the parameters. You need more such messages with CRCs, including messages of differing lengths.

Comment: OK.. I can generate a bunch more messages from the device.  Getting data of differing lengths might be a little fiddly, but I'll give it a go.  Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps I've compiled it wrong.  I generated more data, including different length messages, but it's been running for 2-3 days now, just producing the same output:                                                            ./reveng: searching: width=8  poly=0x01  refin=false  refout=false
./reveng: searching: width=8  poly=0x01  refin=false  refout=false
Over and over

Comment: Just a followup on this.  It was indeed wrong, I needed to change some of the defines in the config.h file for my 64bit arch.  Once I did that, it found the crc in under 5 seconds.  Thanks so much!